# no or unknown cpufreq driver is active after disabling intel_pstate driver

Tags: cpu-frequency

After disabling **intel_pstate** driver, I get the following error:

```
cpupower frequency-info
analyzing CPU 0:
  no or unknown cpufreq driver is active on this CPU
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: Not Available
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: Not Available
  maximum transition latency:  Cannot determine or is not supported.
Not Available
  available cpufreq governors: Not Available
  Unable to determine current policy
  current CPU frequency: Unable to call hardware
  current CPU frequency:  Unable to call to kernel
  boost state support:
    Supported: yes
    Active: yes
```

I would like to use the **acpi-cpufreq** module instead, in order to have the governor userspace available and set specific CPU frequencies.

Comment: How did you disabled **intel_pstate** driver? And, what happens if you *manually insert* the desired one?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when SpeedStep was disabled. I was able to enable it through the BIOS settings.